# getOwnPropertyDescriptor returns undefine when it has a value

Tags: javascript, oop

I have been like one hour trying to solve with getOwnProperty returns undefined, I check my notes and cannot find the reason, could please some1 check or even better explain me why this behaviour??? Main goal in here is just overwrite a property on a method that extends another one.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andresmijares/GpKtb/)

```
var Person = function(firstName, lastName) {
 this.firstName = firstName;
 this.lastName = lastName;
};

Object.defineProperties(Person.prototype, {
  sayHi : {
    value : function() {
     return "Hi there";
    },
    writable: true,
    enumerable : true
  },

  fullName : {
    get : function() {
     return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    },
    configurable : true,
    enumerable : true
  }

 });

 var createEmployee = function(firstName, lastName, ocupation) {

    var employee = new Person(firstName, lastName);
    employee.ocupation = ocupation;

    /*over-w sayHi*/

    var sayHifn = employee.sayHi.bind(employee);

    employee.sayHi = function() {
      return sayHifn() + " my name is " + this.firstName;
    };

    /*over-w fullName*/

    var fullName = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(employee, "fullName");
    var fullNameFn = fullName.get.bind(employee);

    Object.defineProperty(employee, 'fullName', {
     get : function() {
      return fullNameFn() + " this is o-w ";
     }

    });

    return employee;

  };

  var record = createEmployee('jhon', 'doe', 'eng');
  console.log(record);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason you're getting `undefined` is that the `employee` variable does not have an "own" property called `fullName`. That property belongs to `Person.prototype`.

Give this a try:

```
var fullName = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Person.prototype, "fullName");
```

If you change that line, the rest of your code should work as-is.

**For reference (emphasis added):**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor

> The Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor() method returns a property descriptor for an own property (***that is, one directly present on an object, not present by dint of being along an object's prototype chain***) of a given object.

Comment: that was one of my thought (I'm a noob), but when I instance the object Person into employee, I thought I was passing all the properties... I'm totally lost at it :(, thaks for ur help

Comment: When you create a new `Person` object with `new Person()` the new object _has_ all the properties that you defined on `Person.prototype`, but they are not its "own" properties. That's the important distinction here.

Comment: so, when I set properties outside the constructor with the Object.defineProperties, I can access them but they do not directly belong to it???

Comment: That's close, but not quite right. When you set properties using `Object.defineProperties` (or when you just use the `=` operator), they directly belong to the object on which you created them, but they do _not_ directly belong to objects that are created from that base object. When you call `Object.defineProperties` around line 5, you are creating properties that directly belong to `Person.prototype`. When you create a new `Person` object, you can access those properties on the new object, but they will continue to belong to `Person.prototype`. (continued...)

Comment: ... When you call `Object.defineProperty` at the end of the `createEmployee` function, _then_ you are creating a property that directly belongs to the new object, and this overrides the one that was inherited from `Person.prototype`.

Comment: more clear impossible, I really appreciate you take the time to explain, thanks a lot!

Comment: This saved me after hours messing with **TypeScript Decorators on get|set accessors**!